# How do I open two windows on launch in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, mahapps.metro

I feel like I am missing something very fundamental here, but I can't seem to find an answer.

When my app launches, I want a second `window` based on existing `xaml` to open in addition to `MainWindow.xaml`.  I've found a lot about using code-behind to create a NEW `window`, but I want to open a `window` that is predefined in another `xaml` file.

Both are using MahApps and are defined as

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class=...
  ...
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

The second `window` is called `ControlWindow.xaml` and sits in the root with `MainWindow.xaml`

Thank you

EDIT:

When trying to create and show the window in the App_Startup event in app.xaml.cs, even though the window inherits from the same class as MainWindow.xaml, it does not have the Show() method available.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace RollCallDisplayDemo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ControlWindow.xaml.cs

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace RollCallDisplayDemo
{
    public partial class ControlWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public ControlWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading;

namespace RollCallDisplayDemo
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow NewWindowA = new MainWindow();
            ControlWindow NewWindowB = new ControlWindow();
        }

        static App()
        {
            DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
        }
    }
}
```

NewWindowA acts as you would expect and allows a new instance to be created and shown.  NewWindowB only has the InitializeComponent method available, nothing else which should inherited from the MetroWindow class.

Comment: You can hook into the Application startup event and from the App.Xaml.cs file you can then do whatever you want

Comment: Right, but after subscribing to that, how do I launch a preexisting xaml file as a new, separate window?  All I can find is how to create a NEW window that is defined in code-behind.  Not sure what the downvote was for...

Comment: In XAML, you **define** a window and its content, but don't **create** it. You have to **create** a new window using the `new` operator anyway. Your `MainWindow` is being also **created** by a `new` operator, you just don't see it - the Framework hides this from you.

Comment: OK, I'm adding additional information with the behavior I am seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call NewWindowB.Show() to make it visible. Also there's no need to override the way the main window is being created, just do something like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);

        ControlWindow NewWindowB = new ControlWindow();
        NewWindowB.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark.  It turns out that the solution had to be rebuilt for the Show() method to become available on NewWindowB.  I appreciate the working code example.